# Ajax request to pre-download video(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, video

I have been trying to download a video (which will ultimately be from my own resource) and while the video is downloading I want to show a loading message.

Once it is fully downloaded I want to hide the loading icon and have the video ready to be played.

I am having trouble getting the video file and setting it to the video attribute in the HTML. Here is the code I am using...

JS:

```
var root = 'https://crossorigin.me/http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4';

function loadVideo() {
  $('.loading').show();
  $.ajax({
    url: root,
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(function(data) {
    $('.loading').hide();
    console.log("done");
    $('video').attr('src', data);
    $("video")[0].load();
    //console.log(data);
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loading animated bounce infinite">
Loading
</div>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>


</video>
```

Comment: Do I get it correct, and your root variable is the video? In that case you don't need an ajax request, you simply set the src of the video element, and listen to loadeddata. Your video is "completely loaded" or better has enough data to run, if the readyState is 4.

Comment: Yes, root is the video url. Ultimately I will have a collection of videos that I want to predownload then they could be played depending on which is selected without having to load. It doesn't seem like creating a collection of video tags with src's pointing to the videos and watching all the loadeddata to see if they are available would be very clean. But if there is a better way using this method I open to using it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an ajax request for this. You could simply set the source of the video element, and then listen to `loadeddata`. There are 4 different [readyStates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) you can check for. `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA` (readyState 4) stands for:

> Enough data is available—and the download rate is high enough—that the media can be played through to the end without interruption.

An implementation for this could look like this:

```
function loadVideo(videoURL, $player) {
  $player = $videoObj || $('video');
  $('.loading').show();
  $player.attr('src', videoURL);
  var player = $player[0];
  player.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
      if(player.readyState == 4) {
        // or whatever you want to do 
        // in case the video has enough data
        $('.loading').hide();
      }
  });
}
```

In case you really need the "complete" state (the 100%), you could use the `progress` event to determine how much of the video has been buffered, in case the buffer is 100%, the video should be completely loaded.

```
function loadVideoCompleted(videoURL, $player) {
  $player = $videoObj || $('video');
  $('.loading').show();
  $player.attr('src', videoURL);
  var player = $player[0];
  player.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
      var percentageBuffered = 0;

        if (player.buffered.length > 0 
            && player.buffered.end && player.duration) {
            percentageBuffered = player.buffered.end(0) / player.duration;
        } else if (player.bytesTotal != undefined && 
            player.bytesTotal > 0 && player.bufferedBytes != undefined) {
            percentageBuffered = player.bufferedBytes / player.bytesTotal;
        }

        if (percentageBuffered == 1) { 
             // or whatever you want to do in case
             // 100% of the video has been buffered
             $('.loading').hide();
        }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tested this and while it does work is there any way to get it to fully download as I researched and it seems there are only 4 levels of readyState so the video will not be fully downloaded.

Comment: @okayilltry Yes there are "only" 4 levels. I have updated my answer, readyState 4, is fine in case you want to play the video. I added a second approach which tests the buffer to detect if the video is loaded completely.